# Need to find sum of data based on an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, match, sumifs

Attached is an image of a sample of my work. I usually have columns F & G (NAME:) on its own sheet/tab.

Also, columns I to L (store/date/amnt/name) are also usually on a third sheet/tab in the same workbook.

I am trying to find the total based on date in column A. I need to fill in Column B, based on the list in Column F. This should be pulled from Columns I to L (shows dates and names and amounts). Is there a way to do this?

While this is a short list and example, my actual list is over 50 items long for column F (name).

Sample of what my work would look like

[image: Sample of what my work would look like]

To find the totals based on date and column F and exclude items not in this list.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SUMIFS()` & `SUM()`:

[image]

---

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($L$2:$L$16,$K$2:$K$16,$F$2:$F$4,$J$2:$J$16,A2))
```

---

Or, you could spill all at once using `BYROW()`

[image]

---

```
=BYROW(A2:A9,LAMBDA(x,SUM(SUMIFS(Sheet3!D2:D16,Sheet3!C2:C16,Sheet2!A2:A4,Sheet3!B2:B16,x))))
```

---